# Finding $\left\lfloor\frac{a}{2} \right\rfloor \mod p$ knowing $a \mod p$ and $a \mod 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Knowing $$(a \mod p)\ \text{and}\ (a \mod 2)$$ can we definitely say what is $$\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2}\right\rfloor \mod p$$ where $p$ is a prime. If not possible what else is required to do the same?

Comment: If $a\equiv1\pmod2, a=2m+1, a\equiv2m+1\pmod p$  $\left\lfloor\dfrac a2\right\rfloor\equiv m\pmod p$

If $a\equiv0\pmod2, a=2m, a\equiv2m\pmod p$  $\left\lfloor\dfrac a2\right\rfloor\equiv m\pmod p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By knowing $a\!\!\mod p$ and $a\!\!\mod 2$, we know $a\!\!\mod 2p$ by Chinese Remainder Theorem.

As such, let $a=2pq+r$, where $q$ and $r$ are the quotient and remainder.

$$\left\lfloor\frac{a}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{2pq+r}{2}\right\rfloor\\=\left\lfloor\frac{2pq+r}{2}\right\rfloor\\=pq+\left\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor\equiv\left\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor\mod p$$

Comment: Actually I don't know the exact value of a. I only know $$a\ mod\ x$$ where x is any positive integer. Now how to approach this ?

Comment: The intermediate steps use $q$, although you only know $r$. The aim of these steps is to show that $q$ does not matter.

Comment: Got it.Thanks for your time.